# turn a number based on passed in value to at least 6 digit and max 8 digit

Tags: php, math, modulo

```
public static function generateReceiptNumber(int $id)
{
     $receipt_number = sprintf('%06d', $id % 100000000);
     return $receipt_number;
}
```

I am having the above code to help me to transform a passed in $id to a minimum 6 digit and maximum 8 digit number. eg: 000001 - 99999999

But this code has a flaws that when the $id equal to 100000000, it will return me 000000,
how can i enhance the code above to give me 000001 instead?

So and so forth, the $id is the database incremental id.

The purpose of wanted to achieve this is because, i have a display text box which the text limit is only 8 digit, i can only restarted the number back to 000001 and continue the count to repeat.

Comment: `$id` being a _database incremental id_ shouldn't need you to do these things.

Comment: @nice_dev, i need to do this because of the incremental id will keep increasing, meanwhile my display value has limitation to display only 8 digit max, so that is why i need to restart the display value back from the beginning

Comment: So what should be output for 999999999, 99999999, 99999999999999, 9999999900, 65000000000 etc? You haven't added the cases yet and the output you expect.

Comment: @nice_dev, Olivier has sorted out the solution, and i have been trying a few number, it seem to getting the correct output, you can reference to that

Comment: I am open to learning but only if there is something new for me to learn about. These basic math stuff is obviously easy and the reason why you had only 1 apparently correct answer is because you have an incomplete question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
function generateReceiptNumber(int $id)
{
    while($id>=100000000)
        $id -= 100000000 - 1;
    return sprintf('%06d', $id);
}
```

Comment: this solution is brilliant, thanks.

However, when the $id equal to 999999999, it will return 100000000 instead of 000001

Comment: brilliant solution, thanks bud. appreciate that

Comment: brilliant solution, i was trying so hard just now and couldn't make it, I learn something now

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function generateReceiptNumber(int $id)
{
    // Handle the special case when $id is 100000000
    if ($id === 100000000) {
        return '000001';
    }

    // Use modulo to limit the ID to the range 0 to 99,999,999
    $limited_id = $id % 100000000;
    
    // Format the limited ID with leading zeros to ensure at least 6 digits
    $receipt_number = sprintf('%06d', $limited_id);
    
    return $receipt_number;
}
```

please check this answer if it will help you.

Comment: thanks for the solution.

however, when the $id is equal to 1000000000, it will return 000000 instead of 000001